# fs.writefile only execute in last function in node js

Tags: regex, angularjs, node.js, fs

My program has three functions shown below,

```
    var userId = req.userId;
    var appId = req.body.appId;

    var main = 'temp/' + userId + '/templates/' + appId + '/css/main.css';

    var color = req.body.color;
    var font = req.body.font;
    var fontSize = req.body.fontSize;

        replaceThemecolor(color);
        replaceFont(font);
        replaceFontSize(fontSize);

    function replaceThemecolor(color) {
        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            var regex =/(\.made-easy-themeColor\s*{[^}]*color\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/;
            var result = data.replace(regex, "$1" + color + "$3");
            console.log(color);
            fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }

    function replaceFont(font)  {
        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            var regex =/(\.made-easy-themeFont\s*{[^}]*font-family\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/;
            var result = data.replace(regex, "$1" + font + "$3");
            console.log(font);
            fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
            });
                        console.log(result);
        })
    }

    function replaceFontSize(fontSize)  {
        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            var regex =/(\.made-easy-themeFontSize\s*{[^}]*font-size\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/;
            var result1 = data.replace(regex, "$1" + fontSize + "em" + "$3");
            console.log(fontSize);
            fs.writeFile(main, result1, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
```

In here only the last function executes all the time, when I execute them seperately they work well, but the problem arise when all the funtions execute at once. Is it a problem with fs.writeFile function? I want to execute three of this functions together, is there a way to do this? All the functions here work well when they execute seperately.

Comment: Use writeFileSync instead of writeFile to avoid sync problem. Here you are working on the same file, so issue may be there

Comment: no it is not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file functions are async.  You cannot run them at the same time because they will conflict and one will overwrite the changes of the other.  You must run one, then when it finishes, run the other.

Or, even better, only read the file once, the process the data with all your changes, then write it once.

---

If you were going to run them sequentially, then you would need to pass a callback to each of your functions that is called when it is done so then you know when to start the next function.

---

But, I think a better solution is to pass an array of replace instructions and just process all of them on one read and write of the file.  I will work on a code example for that.

Here's a way to do all the updates in one read/write of the file and uses promises to know when the operation is done:

```
function updateFile(filename, replacements) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                // now cycle through and do all the replacements
                for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
                    data = data.replace(replacements[i].regex, replacements[i].replacer);
                }
                fs.writeFile(filename, data, 'utf-8', function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

updateFile(main, [{regex: /(\.made-easy-themeColor\s*{[^}]*color\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/, replacer: "$1" + color + "$3"}, 
                {regex: /(\.made-easy-themeFont\s*{[^}]*font-family\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/, replacer: "$1" + font + "$3"}, 
                {regex: /(\.made-easy-themeFontSize\s*{[^}]*font-size\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/, replacer: "$1" + fontSize + "em$3"}]).then(function() {
                    // update done successfully
                }, function(err) {
                    // error
                });
```

With some more work, you could probably abstract out just the keywords from the regular expressions too so you only need to pass in the keywords, but I'll leave that to another time.

---

And here's a simplified version:

```
function updateFile(filename, replacements) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            var regex, replaceStr;
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                // now cycle through and do all the replacements
                for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
                    regex = new Regex("(\\" + replacements[i].rule + "\\s*{[^}]*" + replacements[i].target + "\\s*:\\s*)([^\\n;}]+)([\\s*;}])");
                    replaceStr = "$1" + replacements[i].replacer + "$3";
                    data = data.replace(regex, replaceStr);
                }
                fs.writeFile(filename, data, 'utf-8', function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

updateFile(main, [
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeColor", target: "color", replacer: color}, 
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeFont", target: "font-family", replacer: font}, 
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeFontSize", target: "font-size", replacer: fontSize + "em"} 
    ], function() {
        // update done successfully
    }, function(err) {
        // error
});
```

And, you don't have to use the promise at all if you don't want to know when it's all done or be able to return errors (which I wouldn't recommend, but the code is simpler).

```
function updateFile(filename, replacements) {
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        var regex, replaceStr;
        if (err) { return; }
        // now cycle through and do all the replacements
        for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
            regex = new Regex("(\\" + replacements[i].rule + "\\s*{[^}]*" + replacements[i].target + "\\s*:\\s*)([^\\n;}]+)([\\s*;}])");
            replaceStr = "$1" + replacements[i].replacer + "$3";
            data = data.replace(regex, replaceStr);
        }
        fs.writeFile(filename, data, 'utf-8');
    });
}

updateFile(main, [
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeColor", target: "color", replacer: color}, 
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeFont", target: "font-family", replacer: font}, 
        {rule: ".made-easy-themeFontSize", target: "font-size", replacer: fontSize + "em"} 
    ], function() {
        // update done successfully
    }, function(err) {
        // error
});
```

Notice how easy it would be to add more replacements.  You simply add one more line to the array you pass `updateFile()`.

Comment: Answer works well and less code, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is inherently asynchronous. As such, you're doing three read operations in quick succession, and then trying to write to a file that's already file locked, or at the very least, when it was read, did not contain the write changes. I'd use something more like `async`'s series or waterfall methods to solve this.

```
var async = require("async");
var userId = req.userId;
var appId = req.body.appId;

var main = 'temp/' + userId + '/templates/' + appId + '/css/main.css';

var color = req.body.color;
var font = req.body.font;
var fontSize = req.body.fontSize;

async.series({
    replaceThemecolor: function(callback) {
        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            var regex = /(\.made-easy-themeColor\s*{[^}]*color\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/;
            var result = data.replace(regex, "$1" + color + "$3");
            console.log(color);
            fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function(err) {
                callback(err);
            });
        });
    },
    replaceFont: function(callback) {
        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            var regex = /(\.made-easy-themeFont\s*{[^}]*font-family\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/;
            var result = data.replace(regex, "$1" + font + "$3");
            console.log(font);
            fs.writeFile(main, result, 'utf-8', function(err) {
                callback(err);
            });
        })
    },
    replaceFontSize: function(callback) {
        fs.readFile(main, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            var regex = /(\.made-easy-themeFontSize\s*{[^}]*font-size\s*:\s*)([^\n;}]+)([\s*;}])/;
            var result1 = data.replace(regex, "$1" + fontSize + "em" + "$3");
            console.log(fontSize);
            fs.writeFile(main, result1, 'utf-8', function(err) {
                callback(err);
            });
        });
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    // results is empty, but now the operation is done.
});
```

Comment: @adithya - why read/write the same file 3 times when you could read it once, make all three changes, then write it once?

Comment: @jfriend00 touché, but let's not get away from WHY the problem occurred in the first place :D

Comment: @remus - exactly.  If you only read/write the file once, then the problem doesn't even have a chance to occur.  Improve the algorithm for solving the original problem and this new async conflict that was created by a poor solution just goes away.

Comment: @remus jifriend00's answer works well, no need to install async and less code, :). That works well